# En que tipo de variable de java almaceno un valor TIME de Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, time

tengo datos de tipo TIME en mi base de datos y quisiera traer estos a una variable en java que me permita hacer operaciones(suma de tiempos,comparar quien es mayor).
[image: mysql]
he intentado usar variable de tipo java.sql.Time pero no llega a asignarse;

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar qué código has probado?

Comment: Tengo una clase llamada Tolerancia en el que declaro las variables
    private Time diferencia;
    private Time tolerancia;
    private int id;

con sus respectivos get y set

Comment: y este metodo para traer los datos del Mysql 
@Override
    public Tolerancia ObtenerTolerancia(String dni) {
        System.out.println("dni"+dni);
        Tolerancia t = new Tolerancia();
        try {
            Connection cn = Conexion.Conectar();
            String sql = "SELECT TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIME,t.ingreso) as diferencia,t.tolerancia,pt.id FROM personal_turno pt " +
                        "INNER JOIN personal p ON pt.personal_dni = p.dni " +
                        "INNER JOIN turno t ON pt.turno_id = t.id " +

Comment: "WHERE p.dni='"+dni+"' AND CURRENT_TIME BETWEEN t.ingreso and t.salida";
            Statement st = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = null;
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            
            if (rs.first()) {
                rs.beforeFirst();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    //cuando tenga resultados
                    t.setDiferencia(rs.getTime(1));
                    t.setTolerancia(rs.getTime(2));
                    t.setId(rs.getInt(3));
                }

Comment: } else {
                //cuando no tenga resultado
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Este personal no trabaja en este turno","Advertemcia",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
            cn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return t;
    }

Comment: tal vez este confuso el codigo ya que estoy usando varias tablas, pero quisiera saber si uds lo almacenan en una variable de tipo TIme, o un String(si es string se tendia que separar la hora minito segundo de la cadena para hacer operaciones) o que otro tipo de variable puedo usar.

Comment: Que versión de java utilizas? Si utilizas java 8 te recomiendo que utilices LocalDateTime https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la clase DateFormat para settear el time, esta te permite manegar la fecha facilmente, y obtener horas, minutos y segundos con los cuales ya puedes realizar las operaciones que quieras

```
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
   Date date = new Date();
   System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: efectivamente funciono formateando la fecha, era lo que faltaba hacer, gracias :)